# Disable click in right side of the slider

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider, click

I need disable only the right bar, it's for four range selector

here the code in plnkr

https://embed.plnkr.co/MdF3aPOTfyXihz4arJxw/

Comment: What have you tried so far..?

Comment: modify .ui-slider-handle.sleep,
a[data-temperature="sleep"] css code, is the class of the bar that I need to modify

Answer (score 0):

Finally i can solve my problem with:

https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

in javascript

```
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
     start: [10, 20, 50],
     connect: [true, true, true, true],
     range: {
        'min': [0],
        'max': [100]
     }
    });


   var connect = slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');
   var color = ["#11c300", "#ff9936","#ffe132","#ff1313" ];

   for (var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++) {
     $(connect[i]).css({"background":color[i]});
   }
   $(".noUi-base, .noUi-connects").css({'position' : 'initial'});
```

in html